# How to know if navigating from other page or from a Task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my app, I have a page where I navigate from the *MainPage.xaml*. A `CameraCaptureTask` is launched from that page.

I would like to know, on page loading, how can I know if I have navigated from *MainPage.xaml*, or it came back from `CameraCaptureTask`.

Using the `NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault()` doesn't help, because, as expected, it returns the *MainPage.xaml*.

I'd like something like:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (/*Navigated-from-MainPage-but-not-from-CameraCaptureTask*/)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this in one of two ways. The first is to listen to the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff707989%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event of the [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
        CameraCaptureTask task = new CameraCaptureTask();
        task.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(OnCaptureTaskCompleted);
        task.Show();

...

    void OnCaptureTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        // Navigated back or took a picture
    }
```

The second way is to check the [NavigationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.navigationmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of the [NavigationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If the value is Back, then you know you navigated back from the CameraCaptureTask (assuming that this page does not navigate to any other pages)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // came back from CameraCaptureTask
    }
}
```

Comment: Since what I want to know is when I haven't navigated back from the task, I think the second approach suits my needs. I will let you know as soon as I try it.